# Make a Filenet offline storage

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine, offline-storage

I have Filenet 5.2 and My storage is a SAN.I need to send a part of it offline.As i found , in CEEM we can make the storage offline by changing its state to offline. But in my solution i cant see that option in my Properties.

My CEEM..............

[image]

From IBM website ..

[image]

only the OPEN,CLOSE,STAND_BY,FULL options are available.
And i found few information saying that this states need to be enable in early stages which is not a valid solution for me now.Is there a other way if doing this ? Or a way I can add this option available ? how can i make this offline ? please help me on this , Many Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Just for information.

Every state of Storage Area is like usage mode.

STAND BY - Storage Area registered in CE but not used to any operations, when ALL other Areas in related Storage Policy not in OPEN state, CE automatically change state from STAND BY to OPEN.

OPEN - Storage Area used by CE to read and write operations. When capacity of Storage Area will be exhausted, CE change state to FULL.

FULL - Storage Area used by CE only for Read operations. All documents stored on this storage Area will be avaliable for read but all new documents and all new versions (even though current version placed on FULL storage area) will be placed to OPEN storage area in related storage policy.

CLOSED - Storage Aread registered in CE but not used for any operations. Content of documents placed on this Storage Area will be not avaliable (if content is not in cache area).

if you change state of SA to CLOSED CE will not use this SA for any operations and you can disconnect your storage. When you connect it again, you can change state of SA to OPEN and CE will continue to use this SA for operations. You HAVE to keep the mount points are exactly the same.

You can't delete the Storage Area, cause of you can't create this storage area again even though you keep the file structure. When you create new storage area CE will initialize root folder of SA with the specific file-structures.

So when you need to make some operations with disconnected storage (device/file SA) you have to change state to CLOSED and make all tasks.

Comment: Hi , Swepss :) , Thanks a lot on the Information . when I change the mode to CLOSE i can see the image(even i can remove it , if in cash it cant remove right ?) in CN and WP . And yes when i remove the storage it give a error saying its cant open ( but it give same if i remove storage when in other modes too) , For now CLOSE is good if i can see what is the SA in error, so i can put part of it close and remove storage and if one day i need it i can identify it with error code :) , But there must be a Offline option(anyway i will give a vote,for usefulness )  .Thanks again Swepss